# jquery - prevAll is working but not nextAll

Tags: jquery, dom-traversal

I'm trying to add a search functionality to my HTML page with the below js/jquery. Basically I try to search for failed/passed/F/P/FAIL/PASS phrased and I want print testTitle,testAssertion and testResult rows for each for the find result.

```
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("table tr").each(function(index) {
        if (index !== 0) {
            $row = $(this);
            $(this).hide();
            var id = $row.find(".assertionResult").text();
            if (id.indexOf(value) === 0) {
                var x = $row.prevAll().find(".testTitle").last();
                var y = $row.nextAll().find(".testResult").first();
                console.log(y.parent().html());


                $(this).show();
                x.parent().show();
                y.parent().show();


            }

        }

    });
    });
```

Element x is displayed but not element y. Any help?

Associated HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
   <form>
      <input id="search" placeholder="Search For text..."/>
       <input id="reset" type="button" value="reset" onclick="testreset()" />
   </form>
<body>
<table  id="table" style="width:80%" align="center" border="4" data-filter="true" data-input="#">
           <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#000000"><font color="#ffffff">Head</font></td>
            <td class="testTitle" bgcolor="#000000"><font color="#ffffff">HEAD</font></td>
            <td bgcolor="#000000"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#000000"><font color="#ffffff">TC# 1[Title]</font></td>
            <td class="testTitle" bgcolor="#000000"><font color="#ffffff">TC#1</font></td>
            <td bgcolor="#000000"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="assertionName">TC# 1[A-1]</td>
            <td class="assertionMessage">TC# 1A-1</td>
            <td class="assertionResult">P</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="assertionName">TC# 1[A-2]</td>
            <td class="assertionMessage">TC# 1 A-2</td>
            <td class="assertionResult">P</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="assertionName">TC# 1[A-3]</td>
            <td class="assertionMessage">TC# 1 A-3</td>
            <td class="assertionResult">F</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td  class="testName" bgcolor="#228B22">TC# 1</td>
            <td  class="testResult" bgcolor="#228B22">PASS</td>
            <td bgcolor="#228B22">P</td>
         </tr>
      </table>

</body>
</html>
```

This HTML has a search box to type in and I have used js/jquery

Comment: Please provide HTML.

Comment: I don't understand the logic of your code.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to find tablerows that have a cell with a class of assertionResult that has text that matches the search criteria. You don't need to loop over every row to accomplish that.

Comment: 'Not working' can mean many things. Please explain what you are expecting to happen and what is actually happening

Comment: I want to get respective testTitle and testResult matching the assertionResult. I'm not sure of the position assertionResult. that is why, I'm using prevAll and nextAll.

Comment: Appologies..Looks like I didn't add more details on my requirements. So When I use my script, my testTitle is displayed but not testResult.

Comment: because you're hiding it with `$(this).hide()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are hiding whilst you are cycling through the rows, that's why you have issues. I think there are easier ways to accomplish what you are trying, but without changing your code too much, you may be able to change the jquery to this. Note the repositioning of the hide and change of the prevAll...

```
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("table tr").hide();
    $("table tr").each(function(index) {
        if (index !== 0) {
            $row = $(this);
          //$(this).hide();
            var id = $row.find(".assertionResult").text();
            if (id.indexOf(value) === 0) {
                var x = $(".testTitle");
                var y = $(".testResult");

                $(this).show();
                x.parent().show();
                y.parent().show();


        }

    }

});
});
```

and fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/j32k95m7/

Comment: Thank you for the modification Sico! Your solution prints all "testTitle" and "testResult". But I want testTitle and testResult only for the "assertionResult" that I'm searching and matched for.

Answer (score 0):

The below solution worked for me when I have more than 1 test case results with pass/FAIL.

```
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
     $("table tr").hide();
    $("table tr").each(function(index) {
        if (index !== 0) {
            $row = $(this);

            var id = $row.find(".assertionResult").text();
            if (id.indexOf(value) === 0) {
                var x = $row.prevAll().find(".testTitle").last();
                var y = $row.nextAll().find(".testResult").first();
                console.log(y.parent().html());


                $(this).show();
                x.parent().show();
                y.parent().show();


            }

        }

    });
});
```